# Displaying images in boxes

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, web-deployment

Part-1  I have to take 6 boxes and display images by clicking on any Box. IF I click on any box, The 1st empty box should display picture and then so on.

Part2- IF the Box which has been Assigned an image where to be clicked again, then that box image should be replaced.

I have Done/Solved The 1st Part OF THE Problem.

But, NOT THE PART 2. if you have better approach to both parts. Then help would be appreciated.

**Template**

```
<div class="container">
      <label for="file-input">
        <div class="container1" >
          <img [src]="url[0]" *ngIf="url" class="imgdisplay" />
        </div>
      </label>

      <label for="file-input">
        <div class="container1">
          <img [src]="url[1]" *ngIf="url" class="imgdisplay" />
        </div>
      </label>

      <label for="file-input">
        <div class="container1">
          <img [src]="url[2]" *ngIf="url" class="imgdisplay" />
        </div>
      </label>

      <label for="file-input">
        <div class="container1">
          <img [src]="url[3]" *ngIf="url" class="imgdisplay" />
        </div>
      </label>

      <label for="file-input">
        <div class="container1">
          <img [src]="url[4]" *ngIf="url" class="imgdisplay" />
        </div>
      </label>

      <label for="file-input">
        <div class="container1">
          <div class="image-upload">
            <div><img [src]="url[5]" *ngIf="url" class="imgdisplay" /></div>

            <input id="file-input" type="file" #img ngModel name="img" [(ngModel)]="model.img" class="customfile"
            accept="image/*" (change)="selectFile($event)" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </label>
    </div>
```

**TS**

```
   model: any = {};
    url: any = [];
  
    selectFile(event: any) {

     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);

     reader.onload = (_event) => {

       this.url.push(reader.result);
      console.log(this.url);

     }
   }
```

I tried to get index and then checking with if else and then replacing it but keep getting index null or undefined. Any help would be appreciated.